# How to create swipeable bottom sheet in React Native?

Tags: react-native, swipe-gesture, bottom-sheet

How to implement exactly the same swipeable bottom sheet in **React Native**:

[image]

[react-swipeable-bottom-sheet](https://github.com/manufont/react-swipeable-bottom-sheet) (demo gif above) lib is working only in React.

I know [react-native-overlay-section](https://github.com/angelsit-web/react-native-overlay-section) but it is opening to the top of the window with bounce animation.

---

**EDIT**

I also tried [react-native-touch-through-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-touch-through-view), but there is a known issue with touches through the `TouchThroughView`...

```
<View style={styles.container}>
 <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.list}
    renderItem={(data) => {
     <View>
       <Text>{"Bla bla bla"}</Text>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.onPress()}>
         <Text>{"THIS IS NOT WORKING ON ANDROID"}</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
    }} />
 </View>
<TouchThroughWrapper style={styles.scrollWrapper}>
  <ListView
    style={styles.scroller}
    dataSource={actionsList}
    renderHeader={() => <TouchThroughView style={styles.touchThroughView} />}
    renderRow={(rowData) => {
      return (
        <Text style={styles.itemRow}>{rowData}</Text>
      )
    }}>
  </ListView>
</TouchThroughWrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement with the help of following package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-touch-through-view

This package allows scroll views and table views to scroll over interactable content without poor performing size and bounds animations.

Comment: Thanks. It is a very nice library but I cannot touch the buttons through the `TouchThroughView` in Android and it makes my app useless. And it seems maintainer does not care about it for a half year.

Comment: It is possible to access buttons through in android also. I have used this in my project also. so can you share your code snippet where are implementing TouchThroughWrapper.

Comment: I have already edited my question. Thus, could you please put somewhere a magic prop that makes it work? I would be great.

Comment: **<TouchThroughWrapper
  style={{
  width: '100%',
  marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 50 : 0}}>
  {
  <List
  style={{
       marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 50
  }} />}</TouchThroughWrapper>** Try like this add margintop property for ios in touchthroughwrapper and for android inside child component.